# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model when crossed references

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and I'm trying to do this:

**user.model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('../../db/mongodb.connector'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

require('./offer.model');
var Offer = mongoose.model('Offer');

var userSchema = new Schema({
    name:                  { type: String },
    myOffers:            [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Offer'}],

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**offer.model.js**

```
var mongoose = require('../../db/mongodb.connector'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;


require('./user.model');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

var commentSchema  = new Schema({

    user:              {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'},
    comment:           {type: String},
    likes:             {type: Number}
});

var offerSchema  = new Schema({
    name:               {type: String},
    comments:           [commentSchema],
    likes:              {type:Number}
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('Offer', offerSchema);
```

My problem is when I execute the server it returns:

```
    D:\WebStorm\Alertame-Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:362
          throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
          ^
    MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
    Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
        at Mongoose.model (D:\WebStorm\myproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:362:13)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\WebStorm\myproject\db\models\offer.model.js:9:21)
.......
```

If I remove the imports in offer.model the server starts normally

```
require('./user.model');
    var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

**EDIT TO EXPLANATION:**
Offers are a individual entity and it would be assigned or not to an existing user (user has an array of assigned offer refs). On the other hand offers have an array of comment refs which be written by existing users.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to include `offer.model` from `user.model` and `user.model` from `offer.model`. Each file tries to include itself.

That is the reason it gives an error of `undefined` schema!

Comment: And then, wich would be the correct way to do this? Offers have their array of comments which each comment have a referenced user. And Users have their array of offers... :p

Comment: Why have you made `offer` as part of `user` schema when you have defined a separate schema for `comments`? This looks like a design issue.

Comment: Offers are a individual entity and it would be assigned or not to an existing user (user has an array of assigned offer refs). On the other hand offers have an array of  comment refs wich be writed by existing users. I hope this explains my problem

Comment: Is necessary to import the model wich is in other file to do a ref?

Comment: @Hanzo I am not very sure on this. Would suggest you to give a try :)

Comment: @Hanzo did you able to solve this issue? i'm facing the same one. Please help.